# How to search for rows using an expression in numpy rec array

Tags: python, numpy

Consider i have a numpy recarray as below:

```
r = np.rec.array([(1,2,'Hello'),(2,3,"World")], \
                 dtype=[('foo', 'i4'),('bar', 'i4'), ('baz', 'S10')])
```

Now i want to get all the object that returns 'True' for the following expression stored in dict,

```
expression = {'foo':1,'bar':3.,'baz':'Hello'}
```

> I am looking for a method like **r.select(**expression)** to select me all the objects that match those conditions passed to the select.

expression is dynamic, changes very frequently.

Comment: `bar` is a floating point type: comparisons may not be exact.

Comment: @Evert i have edited my question to avoid confusion, my question is whether there exist a function like r.select(foo=1,bar=3,baz='hello)

Comment: Not a function, but functionality like that: yes.

Comment: I understand the expression is dynamic, but just for the sake of verifying results at our ends, what is the expected output for the sample case?

Comment: I would make a 1element recarray with the same dtype, and use `np.in1d` to find a match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine array comparisons with boolean operators.
For example (with a poor-mans implementations of a float comparison):

```
EPS = 1e-7
mask = np.ones(len(r), dtype=np.bool)
mask &= r['foo'] == 1
mask &= (r['bar'] > 3-EPS) & (r['bar'] < 3+EPS)
mask &= r['baz'] == 'hello'
print(r[mask])
```

Or you can use or, `|` instead of and, `&`, if you prefer that.
(Or a combination, since the two `r['bar']` will have to be `&`-ed anyway.)

Comment: i don't have a static expression, the expressions change dynamically, i have python dictionary that has all the conditions, how can i create a mask from a dictionary of key & value.

Comment: @deepak Use a loop with the key and values in the dict. You can expand the mask step by step. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

If `r` is 1d (or can be flattened) `np.in1d` is a fast search tool.  Most examples are with ints, but it works with a compound dtype as well.

```
In [1127]: r = np.rec.array([(1,2,'Hello'),(2,3,"World")], \
   ......:                  dtype=[('foo', 'i4'),('bar', 'i4'), ('baz', 'S10')]) 

In [1129]: r.shape
Out[1129]: (2,)

In [1130]: expression = {'foo':1,'bar':3.,'baz':'Hello'}
```

Make a 1 element array from this `expression`:

```
In [1131]: x=np.array((expression['foo'],expression['bar'],expression['baz']), dtype=r.dtype)

In [1132]: x
Out[1132]: 
array((1, 3, b'Hello'), 
      dtype=(numpy.record, [('foo', '<i4'), ('bar', '<i4'), ('baz', 'S10')]))

In [1133]: np.in1d(r,x)
Out[1133]: array([False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Lets expand `r` to include a match:

```
In [1134]: r1 = np.rec.array([(1,2,'Hello'),(1,3,'Hello'),(2,3,"World")], \
                 dtype=[('foo', 'i4'),('bar', 'i4'), ('baz', 'S10')])

In [1135]: np.in1d(r1,x)
Out[1135]: array([False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

I can construct that `expression` array by iterating on the `dtype.names`:

```
In [1138]: tuple([expression[n] for n in r.dtype.names])
Out[1138]: (1, 3.0, 'Hello')

In [1139]: x=np.array(tuple([expression[n] for n in r.dtype.names]), dtype=r.dtype)
```

I'd suggest also looking at `recfunctions`.

```
from numpy.lib import recfunctions
```

Read some of that code to see how developers expect us to process structured arrays.